# numpy.test error in virtualenv with ERROR: test_multiarray.TestNewBufferProtocol.test_relaxed_strides

Tags: numpy

In my ubuntu system,i install numpy in virtualenv with python 2.7. After i install it, using the numpy.test:

```
python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()"
```

there are some errors like this:

### ERROR: test_multiarray.TestNewBufferProtocol.test_relaxed_strides

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zjd/wangliangguo/theano-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
self.test(*self.arg)
File "/home/zjd/wangliangguo/theano-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/test_multiarray.py", line 5366, in test_relaxed_strides fd.write(c.data)
TypeError: 'buffer' does not have the buffer interface
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with Python 2.7.3.  Upgrading to Python 2.7.11 fixed it for me.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and the default apt-get repositories didn't have Python 2.7.11, so I followed these instructions: https://superuser.com/a/942296